# Can't assign 0 to an array if it was in an assocc in php.

Tags: php, null, zero

Here's some php code. 0 is find in an associative array explicitly. If I try to put it in another one, it doesn't get assigned. The only way I know how to get around this is to explicitly check for it to be 0 using `===`. Is this the only way?

```
<?php
        $vars['one'] = '31234'; 
        $vars['two'] = 'sldf'; 
        $vars['three'] = 1 - 1;  
        $return_array = []; 
        foreach ($vars as $key => $value){
            echo "---------------Just value<br>"; 
            var_dump($value); 
            echo "<br>";  
            $value != '' ? ($return_array[$key] = $value) : null; 
            echo "---------------array of key<br>"; 
            var_dump($return_array[$key]); 
            echo "<br>"; 
        }   
?>
```

I get this nice thing back.

```
---------------Just value
string(5) "31234" 
---------------array of key
string(5) "31234" 
---------------Just value
string(4) "sldf" 
---------------array of key
string(4) "sldf" 
---------------Just value
int(0) 
---------------array of key
NULL
```

Any way better around this than `if ($key === 0) { // stuff }`?

Comment: What are you exactly trying to achieve? "0 is find in an associative array explicitly." <-- What is the sentence supposed to mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using "loose comparison" when doing `$value != ''`. This evaluates to false for 0 also. See the table for loose comparison [here](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).

If you used `$value !== ''` instead, it would insert the 0 to the array.